# Where can I get more information about my submission error?

Tags: support, error-message

OK..so I get the big red box. Any guidelines on how to resolve it?

Using FF23.0.1 and Chrome 29.0 both show same red box when I click button to submit. Box appears about 30 seconds after I click submit.

[image: SO_submission_error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a VPN Connection at work. As long as I was using VPN Connection, I could not post content. When I disconnected my VPN connection I was able to submit my question.

A solution that works for me: Disconnect VPN connection and try asking question.

Answer (score 4):

If you open Chrome's Web Inspector and go to the Network tab:

[image: The Network tab is highlighted.]

You will see a list of any new requests. When you click the button, you should see one saying (pending), and when you get the error message, you should be able to click on the offending request to get more information.

Firefox should have something similar, but I'm not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is thinking that the error is from the Stack Exchange site, but actually this error occurs when you do not have a live Internet connection when you submit the question. So the error is on the client side.

Actually what happens when you hit Post on your question is I think Stack Exchange makes an AJAX call, but when you do not have a live Internet connection it cannot make an AJAX call, so it gives an error. Since the error is at the client side Stack Exchange cannot give more detail.

Comment: have i said anything wrong ??